# How to mute sound in code when using react-native-youtube?

Tags: react-native

I am using this react native plugin (react-native-youtube) - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-youtube.

How to use code to mute the sound when playing a youtube video, and unmute sound when the video becomes fullscreen.

```
<YouTube
                        apiKey = {googleAPIKey}
                        videoId="videoId" // The YouTube video ID
                        loop={true}
                        play = {this.state.isPlaying} // control playback of video with true/false
                        fullscreen = {false} // control whether the video should play in fullscreen or inline
                        controls={2}
                        showinfo={false} 
                        ref={this._youTubeRef}
                        style={{alignSelf: 'stretch', height: youtubeHeight, borderRadius:5}}
                        onError={e => {
                          this.setState({ error: e.error });
                        }} 
                        onReady={e => {
                          //this._youTubeRef.current.mute(); -> error with message mute is not a function.
                          this.setState({ isReady: true });
                        }}
                        onChangeState={e => {
                          this.setState({ status: e.state });
                        }}
                        onChangeQuality={e => {
                          this.setState({ quality: e.quality });
                        }}
                        onChangeFullscreen={e => {
                          this.setState({ fullscreen: e.isFullscreen });
                        }}
                        onProgress={e => {
                          this.setState({ currentTime: e.currentTime });
                        }}
                  />
```

Please help me.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using this.props.navigation.isFocused() to detect if leaving the current screen and if leave then set the isPlaying variable to false to pause the video.